# How can I use jQuery to change my HTML so each text in an <li> is surrounded by a <span>?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="breadcrumb">
    <li>abc</li>
    <li><span>xx</span></li>
    <li>xxxxx</li>
</ul>
```

How can I use jQuery to make it so that every `<li>` has its contents enclosed with a `<span>`. Here is what I would like the HTML to look like:

```
<ul id="breadcrumb">
    <li><span>abc</span></li>
    <li><span>xx</span></li>
    <li><span>xxxxx</span></li>
</ul>
```

Please note. It's possible that some of the contents of the `<li>` are already enclosed in a `<span>`. I don't want to do anything to those.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('span').length == 0){
        $(this).wrapInner('<span/>');
    }
})
```

Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9S4tH/

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
//iterate through each <li> child of #breadcrumb
$("#breadcrumb > li").each(function() {
   //select only those li who doesn't have span child
   if($(this).children('span').length < 1) {
        //wrap it with span
        $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");

   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("li").each(function() {
    if (!$('span', this).length) {
        $(this).wrapInner('<span></span>');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k4fKX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, though I confess I havent tested it:

```
$('#breadcrumb li')each(function() {
    $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#breadcrumb li').each(function() {
        $(this).html($('<span />').html($(this).html()));
    });
});
```

**How it works:**

For each li in breadcrumb, set the li's html to a span element, and set the span's html content to the li's original html content.

**Note:**

jQuery recommends that when creating new elements, you do it like this...

```
$('<span />')
```

as opposed to appending literal text like so...

```
'<span>' + text + '</span>'
```

as the latter can have undesired results in some instances.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$("#breadcrumb li").each(function(item) {
    // $(this) - its your <li> element
    $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WrapInner() jquery method .

```
 $(this).wrapInner('<span></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit more elegant, try this:

```
$("#breadcrumb li:not(:has(span))").wrapInner("<span>");​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39HC4/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li:not(:has(span))').each(function(){
   $(this).html('<span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpH2U/)